# How to safely combine strings into file path and open filewriter?

Tags: java, file, path

Is there a more elegant way to do the following?

```
try (FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(Paths.get(folder,fileName).toAbsolutePath().toString())){
```

I have folder path and filename as string and I want to safely combine them. For example if

```
String folder = "/tmp/"
String fileName = "/myfile.txt"
```

to not end up with

```
"/tmp//myfile.txt"
```

or with

```
String folder = "/tmp"
String fileName = "myfile.txt"
```

to not end up with

```
"/tmpmyfile.txt"
```

The way I am using is transforming String to path and back to String which feels weird, but it looks like FileWriter does not accept Path directly.

Is there some more elegant solution than the one I have?

Comment: Add code to check for leading/training slashes and adjust accordingly.

Comment: The other option is to leave the slashes, most if not all filesystems will ignore them and code will code just fine, unless you are concerned on how is it presented to the user, then yes, just remove them manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Files.newBufferedWriter(Path, OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-).

```
try (Writer myWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(folder, fileName))) {
    // other code
}
```

Note that, while the `FileWriter` constructor uses the JVM's default encoding, this method uses the `UTF-8` encoding, which is considered generally more useful. If you need to replicate the behavior of the `FileWriter` constructor, use

```
Files.newBufferedWriter(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Comment: @boucekv  Note that  `java.nio.file.Files` was introduced in Java 1.7 along with `java.nio.file.Paths` and many other classes, so they were designed to work together, whereas `java.io.FileWriter` has been available since v1.1. Because of this is often useful to search in the doc for other classes that replace the old functionality, the the one @Izruo is suggesting.